# How to fix Pyrogram client creation error in DearPyGui app?

Tags: python, user-interface, telegram, telegram-bot, mtproto

I cant create pyrogram client to input an user accaunt data to create program which help to use accaunt automaticly in telegram. when I get text from lables api hash and api id and send it in gunc registr it gives an error when I try to create a client:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yablo\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Lessons\calc\some.py", line 58, in inp
    registr(inputed_hash,inputed_api)
  File "C:\Users\yablo\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Lessons\calc\some.py", line 51, in registr
    app = pyrogram.Client("my_app",inputed_api,inputed_hash)
  File "C:\Users\yablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\client.py",         line 267, in __init__
    self.dispatcher = Dispatcher(self)
  File "C:\Users\yablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\yablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in     get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-6'.

import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg
import dearpygui.demo as demo
import pyrogram
from pyrogram  import Client,filters,idle

dpg.create_context()
dpg.create_viewport(title="program",width=500,height=500)


# font for ukrainian letters =========================================================================
big_let_start = 0x00C0  # Capital "A" in cyrillic alphabet
big_let_end = 0x00DF  # Capital "Я" in cyrillic alphabet
small_let_end = 0x00FF  # small "я" in cyrillic alphabet
remap_big_let = 0x0410  # Starting number for remapped cyrillic alphabet
alph_len = big_let_end - big_let_start + 1  # adds the shift from big letters to small
alph_shift = remap_big_let - big_let_start  # adds the shift from remapped to non-remapped


with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("notomono-regular.ttf", 20) as default_font:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Default)
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
        biglet = remap_big_let  # Starting number for remapped cyrillic alphabet
        dpg.add_char_remap( 178 , 1030 )# Remap the big cyrillic letter
        dpg.add_char_remap( 179 , 1110 )# Remap the small cyrillic letter
        dpg.add_char_remap( 175 , 1031 )# Remap the big cyrillic letter
        dpg.add_char_remap( 191 , 1111 )# Remap the small cyrillic letter
        for i1 in range(big_let_start, big_let_end + 1):  # Cycle through big letters in cyrillic alphabet
            dpg.add_char_remap(i1, biglet)  # Remap the big cyrillic letter
            dpg.add_char_remap(i1 + alph_len, biglet + alph_len)  # Remap the small cyrillic letter
            biglet += 1  # choose next letter
        
def to_cyr(instr):  # conversion function
    out = []  # start with empty output
        for i in range(0, len(instr)):  # cycle through letters in input string
            if ord(instr[i]) in range(big_let_start, small_let_end + 1):  # check if the letter is cyrillic
                out.append(chr(ord(instr[i]) + alph_shift))  # if it is change it and add to output list
            elif ord(instr[i]) == 178:
                out.append(chr(1030 ))
            elif ord(instr[i]) == 179:
                out.append(chr(1110 ))
            elif ord(instr[i]) == 175:
                out.append(chr(1031 ))
            elif ord(instr[i]) == 191:
                out.append(chr(1111  ))
            else:
                out.append(instr[i])  # if it isn`t don`t change anything and just add it to output list
        return(''.join(out))  # convert list to string

#=====================================================================================================

def registr(inputed_hash,inputed_api):
    app = pyrogram.Client("my_app",inputed_api,inputed_hash)
    #app = pyrogram.Client("my_app",api_hash=inputed_hash,api_id=inputed_api)

def inp(sender):
    if sender == "get_api_hash,id_label":
        inputed_hash = to_cyr(dpg.get_value("hash"))
        inputed_api  = to_cyr(dpg.get_value("api"))
        registr(inputed_hash,inputed_api)
    



with dpg.window(label="хз",height=300,width=500):

    with dpg.menu_bar():
        with dpg.menu(label="dv",tag="12"):
            dpg.add_menu_item(label="ji")
        
        with dpg.menu(label="dv2",tag="23"):
            dpg.add_text(label="mop")
        
        
    with dpg.tab_bar():
        with dpg.tab(label="accaunt"):
            api_hash_lable = dpg.add_input_text(label="api hash",tag="hash")
            api_id_lable= dpg.add_input_text(label="api id",tag="api")
            dpg.bind_item_font(api_hash_lable, default_font)
            dpg.bind_item_font(api_id_lable, default_font)
            dpg.add_button(label="log in",tag="get_api_hash,id_label",callback=inp)

        with dpg.tab(label="oob2"):
            dpg.add_button(label="h")
        





dpg.setup_dearpygui()
dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

I tried to create threads to do fix it, but it helps to go to line with creating a client, and nothing more. how to fix it